# C++ recursion: Find all possible purchase-combinations of products with different prices

Tags: c++, recursion, subset-sum

Lets assume I have n amount of money and item A costs 1, item B costs 2 and item C costs 3.

How can I print all possible combination of purchases with a given amount of money?

Output for n=3 should look like: C - A,B - B,A - A,A,A

The Solution I came up with sadly doesn't work.

```
void purchase(int money)
{
    if (money == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (money > 3)
        {
            cout << "C ";
            purchase(money - 3);
        }
        else if (money > 2)
        {
            cout << "B ";
            purchase(money - 2);
        }
        else if (money == 1)
        {
            cout << "A ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need combinations or permutations?  Your example counts permutations.

Comment: `if (money > 3){ cout << "C ";` Do you need _more_ than 3 dollars to buy a C which costs exactly 3 dollars?

Comment: yes, permutations

Comment: Moreover, if you try the recursion on C because you have more than 3 money, why you don't try also on B and A?

Comment: Should the solution also consider `A,A`, `B` and `A` as valid outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of your path, as well as test for the correct values and include all possibilities.

```
void purchase(int money, string path = "")
{
    if (money == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (money > 2)
    {
        string p = path + "C ";
        cout << p << "- ";
        purchase(money - 3, p);
    }
    if (money > 1)
    {
        string p = path + "B ";
        cout << p << "- ";
        purchase(money - 2, p);
    }
    string p = path + "A ";
    cout << p << "- ";
    purchase(money - 1, p);
}
```

This solution lists all possible purchases, including ones that don't exhaust your cash supply.

Comment: Be careful: string concatenation using the + operator creates a new string each time.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: I was referring to the performance of such operation (considering the exponential number of times it is performed). A part of this, the code works fine!

Comment: What has to be changed, in order to only accept possibilities that use all of the given money? And is performance really that much slower due to the string concatention, as that is noticeable?

Comment: I don't like to put comparisons, but.. calling it with `money=30` the function needs 12 seconds to be computed on my notebook (excluding all cout), while my proposed solution needs less than 0.3 seconds.

Comment: Your proposed solution doesn't include the same number of combinations.

Comment: I did the test removing the condition `if (money == 0) {` which excludes combinations that doesn't exhaust the cash supply. Thus the remaining cost is only due to string operations. Consider that each time the program creates a new string, it must do a syscall to allocate new memory and... instead in my case I allocate memory only once.

Comment: I still don't see it as a problem in the given context.  Repeatedly using `cout` is a much bigger problem if you worry about performance.  OP doesn't seem to have a problem with either.

Comment: @LNK2019, you'd wrap each `cout` statement in a test for remaining cash.

Comment: @SidS But then the cout would never be called because checking for remaining cash means checking if money == 0 or? And this can never happen because the overlying if checks if money is > 1 or > 2

Comment: @LNK2019, it could look like this: `void purchase(int money, string path = "")
{
    if (money == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (money > 2)
    {
        string p = path + "C ";
        if (money == 3)
        {
            cout << p << "- ";
        }
        purchase(money - 3, p);
    }
    if (money > 1)
    {
        string p = path + "B ";
        if (money == 2)
        {
            cout << p << "- ";
        }
        purchase(money - 2, p);
    }
    string p = path + "A ";
    if (money == 1)
    {
        cout << p << "- ";
    }
    ...
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Using a support buffer and a buffer function this operation can be implemented in an easy way. Here `str` works as buffer, where I save the letters encountered until now, while `depth` is used to keep the level.

```
void purchase_impl(int money, char * str, int depth) {
    if (money == 0) {
        if (depth > 0) {
            str[depth] = '\0';
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
        return;
    }
    if (money >= 3) {
        str[depth] = 'C';
        purchase_impl(money-3, str, depth+1);
    }
    if (money >= 2) {
        str[depth] = 'B';
        purchase_impl(money-2, str, depth+1);
    }
    if (money >= 1) {
        str[depth] = 'A';
        purchase_impl(money-1, str, depth+1);
    }
}

void purchase(int money)
{
    char * str = (char *) malloc(money+1);
    purchase_impl(money, str, 0);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: @LNK2019, does this answer meet your requirements?